# Prolog =:= operator

Tags: math, prolog, operators, equality, arithmetic-expressions

There are some special operators in Prolog, one of them is `is`, however, recently I came across the `=:=` operator and have no idea how it works.

Can someone explain what this operator does, and also where can I find a predefined list of such special operators and what they do?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
?- 2+3 =:= 6-1.
true.

?- 2+3 is 6-1.
false.
```

Also please see docs http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=is/2

Comment: Basically an arithmetic operator that checks whether the results of some calculation ends in the same outcome? Kind of like Variable is 5+10 but calculated on both sides and then unified, giving true or false as a result.

Answer (score 106):

I think the above answer deserves a few words of explanation here nevertheless.

A short note in advance: Arithmetic expressions in Prolog are just terms ("Everything is a term in Prolog"), which are not evaluated *automatically*. (If you have a Lisp background, think of quoted lists). So `3 + 4` is just the same as `+(3,4)`, which does nothing on its own. It is the responsibility of individual predicates to *evaluate* those terms.

Several built-in predicates do implicit evaluation, among them the arithmetic comparsion operators like `=:=` and `is`. While `=:=` evaluates both arguments and compares the result, `is` accepts and evaluates only its *right* argument as an arithmetic expression.

The *left* argument has to be an atom, either a numeric constant (which is then compared to the result of the evaluation of the right operand), or a variable. If it is a *bound* variable, its value has to be numeric and is compared to the right operand as in the former case. If it is an *unbound* variable, the result of the evaluation of the right operand is bound to that variable. `is` is often used in this latter case, to bind variables.

To pick up on an example from the above linked Prolog Dictionary: To test if a number N is even, you could use both operators:

```
0 is N mod 2  % true if N is even
0 =:= N mod 2 % dito
```

But if you want to capture the result of the operation you can only use the first variant. If X is unbound, then:

```
X is N mod 2   % X will be 0 if N is even
X =:= N mod 2  % !will bomb with argument/instantiation error!
```

Rule of thumb: If you just need arithmetic comparison, use `=:=`. If you want to capture the result of an evaluation, use `is`.

Comment: Why this wasn't selected as the right answer, I would never know ( ._.)

Comment: When using "is" could you have more than one variable on the left-hand side? 
X + Y  = 2 +3 for example.

Comment: @hiswendy What should be the result of this?! Remember that `is` evaluates its right-hand side as an arithmetic expression. That would be 5 in your example. How should 5 than unify with the left-hand side term like `X + Y`?! - The `=/2` predicate you are using is a most general unification function that tries to match and bind two arbitrary terms. It doesn't do automatic arithmetic evaluation, and hence is also quite different from `=:=` which is also discussed here.

Comment: @ThomasH hiswendy is technically correct though in that `?- X + Y = 2 + 3.` produces a result, and that result is `X = 2, Y = 3.` But with CLP arithmetic though, one could do `X + 4 #= 2 + 3.` and get `X = 1.` which is more useful.

Comment: @ErikKaplun I agree when using `=`. But hiswendy's question concerned `is`, and that doesn't work.

Comment: Damn, sir, a good answer. Written 14 years ago, no less.

Answer (score 20):

Complementing the existing answers, I would like to state a few additional points:

## An operator is an operator

First of all, the *operator* `=:=` is, as the name indicates, an **operator**. In Prolog, we can use the predicate `current_op/3` to learn more about operators. For example:

```
?- current_op(Prec, Type, =:=).
Prec = 700,
Type = xfx.
```

This means that the operator `=:=` has **precedence** 700 and is of **type** `xfx`. This means that it is a binary **infix** operator.

This means that you *can*, if you *want*, write a term like `=:=(X, Y)` **equivalently** as `X =:= Y`. In *both cases*, the *functor* of the term is `=:=`, and the *arity* of the term is 2. You can use `write_canonical/1` to verify this:

```
?- write_canonical(a =:= b).
=:=(a,b)
```

## A predicate is not an operator

So far, so good! This has all been a purely *syntactical* feature. However, what you are *actually* asking about is the **predicate** `(=:=)/2`, whose name is `=:=` and which takes 2 *arguments*.

As others have already explained, the predicate `(=:=)/2` denotes **arithmetic equality** of two arithmetic expressions. It is *true* *iff* its arguments *evaluate* to the same number.

For example, let us try the most general query, by which we ask for any solution whatsoever, using *variables* as arguments:

```
?- X =:= Y.
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Hence, this predicate is *not* a true relation, since we cannot use it for *generating* results! This is a quite severe drawback of this predicate, clashing with what you commonly call "declarative programming".

The predicate only works in the very *specific* situation that both arguments are fully instantiated. For example:

```
?- 1 + 2 =:= 3.
true.
```

We call such predicates *moded* because they can only be used in particular *modes* of usage. For the vast majority of beginners, moded predicates are a *nightmare* to use, because they require you to think about your programs *procedurally*, which is quite hard at first and remains hard also later. Also, moded predicates severely *limit the generality* of your programs, because you cannot use them on all directions in which you *could* use pure predicates.

## Constraints are a more general alternative

Prolog also provides much *more general* arithmetic predicates in the form of arithmetic **constraints**.

For example, in the case of *integers*, try your Prolog system's **CLP(FD) constraints**. One of the most important CLP(FD) constraints denotes arithmetic *equality* and is called `(#=)/2`. In complete analogy to `(=:=)/2`, the *operator* `(#=)/2` is also defined as an **infix** operator, and so you can write for example:

```
| ?- 1 + 2 #= 3.

yes
```

I am using GNU Prolog as one particular example, and many other Prolog systems also provide CLP(FD) implementations.

A major attraction of constraints is found in their **generality**. For example, in contrast to `(=:=)/2`, we get with the **predicate** `(#=)/2`:

```
| ?- X + 2 #= 3.

X = 1

| ?- 1 + Y #= 3.

Y = 2
```

*And* we can even ask the **most general** query:

```
| ?- X #= Y.

X = _#0(0..268435455)
Y = _#0(0..268435455)
```

Note how naturally these predicates blend into Prolog and act as **relations** between integer expressions that can be queried in *all directions*.

Depending on the domain of interest, my recommendition is to use CLP(FD), CLP(Q), CLP(B) etc. *instead* of using more low-level arithmetic predicates.

Also see [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd), [clpq](/questions/tagged/clpq) and [clpb](/questions/tagged/clpb) for more information.

Coincidentally, the *operator* `=:=` is used by CLP(B) with a *completely* different meaning:

```
?- sat(A =:= B+1).
A = 1,
sat(B=:=B).
```

This shows that you must distinguish between *operators* and *predicates*. In the above case, the **predicate** `sat/1` has interpreted the given expression as a propositional formula, and in this context, `=:=` denotes equality of Boolean expressions.

Comment: a very nice answer , mat .  I particularly like the way you introduce the usage of op and write_canonical .  op is an extremely feature of prolog , in my opinion .

Comment: However , I disagree strongly with your assertion that an op is not a predicate .  Part of the brilliant genius of prolog , in my opinion , is that every op IS a funktor (predicate) .  In fact , every element of your source becomes a predicate .  In this way it can be seen that the function of tokenizing and parsing in the prolog interprter is to produce a syntax tree , and that syntax tree is entirely specified via funktor .

Answer (score 5):

I found my own answer, http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/prologdict.html

Answer (score 4):

Its an ISO core standard predicate operator, which cannot be bootstrapped from unification (=)/2 or syntactic equality (==)/2. It is defined in section 8.7 Arithmetic Comparison. And it basically behaves as follows:

```
E =:= F :- 
    X is E, 
    Y is F, 
    arithmetic_compare(=, X, Y).
```

So both the left hand side (LHS) and right hand side (RHS) must be arithmetic expressions that are evaluted before they are compared. Arithmetic comparison can compare across numeric types. So we have:

```
   GNU Prolog 1.4.5 (64 bits)

   ?- 0 = 0.0.
   no

   ?- 0 == 0.0
   no

   ?- 0 =:= 0.0.
   yes
```

Answer (score 1):

From Erlang I think it could be good to annotate that as syntax are mostly look alike to Prolog.

`=:=` expression is meaning of exactly equal.

such as in JavaScript you can use `===` to also see if the type of the variables are same.
Basically it's same logic but `=:=` is used in functional languages as Prolog, Erlang.

Not much information but hope it could help in some way.

Answer (score 0):

=:= is a comparison operator.A1 =:= A2  succeeds if values of expressions A1 and A2 are equal.
A1 == A2 succeeds if terms A1 and A2 are identical;