# prolog instantiation error with =:= operator

Tags: prolog

I'm writing a function called subseq which checks if one list is a subsequence of another.

```
subseq([],[]).
subseq([],[Y|Ys]).
subseq([X|Xs],[Y|Ys]) :- X=:=Y, subseq(Xs,Ys).
subseq([X|Xs],[Y|Ys]) :- X=\=Y, subseq([X|Xs],Ys).
```

When I try subseq(X,[1,2]) I get:

```
X = [] ? ;
uncaught exception: error(instantiation_error,(=:=)/2)
```

Why is this happening? My guess is that [] is being operated on by =:=, but how do I check for/prevent this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `=:=` and `=\=` in the wrong context here. Those two operators should be used when you have two expressions at hand and want to evaluate and compare them. In your test, because `X` is not known beforehand, Prolog couldn't evaluate `X` and compare with `Y`.  More information about `=:=` and `=\=` could be found here: [Prolog Operator =:=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417253/prolog-operator).

In your code you only need unification for atoms so one possible fix could be:

```
subseq([],[]).
subseq([],[_|_]).
subseq([X|Xs],[Y|Ys]) :- X=Y, subseq(Xs,Ys).
subseq([X|Xs],[Y|Ys]) :- X\=Y, subseq([X|Xs],Ys).
```

Comment: Many Prolog systems provide dif/2 which you could use in place of (\=)/2. I would not call this predicate subseq/2, though.